# Disable auto-mounting

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I need to disable the auto-mount, and mount my USB dive manually.

I'm also struggling with how to find my USB drive after the auto-mounting has been disabled.

Comment: Duplicate at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369154/176171 with better answers

Answer (score 14):

To figure out which device you just connected, you will get some good hints from running dmesg.

Try:

```
dmesg | tail
```

And look for something like this:

```
[ 7445.572614] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 7445.710242] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[ 7445.710746] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 7445.710971] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 7445.710978] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[ 7446.707999] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 7446.708940] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 7448.482520] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 2015232 512-byte logical blocks: (1.03 GB/984 MiB)
```

Notice the `[sdb]` on the last line I pasted. That means that this device can be found at `/dev/sdb`.

Check you devices by doing `ls /dev/sdb*` and you are likely to see something like:

```
$ ls /dev/sdb*
  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
```

From there on you can go ahead with the exercise of mounting the partition `sdb1`to an empty directory. Skim through the start of `man mount` as a start.

Regarding disabling automount, take a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

> **Configuring Automounting**
>
> To enable or disable automount open a terminal and type dconf-editor
>   followed by the [Enter] key.
>
> Browse to org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.
>
> The automount key controls whether to automatically mount media. If
>   set to true, then Nautilus will automatically mount media such as
>   user-visible hard disks and removable media on start-up and media
>   insertion.
>
> There is another key org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount-open.
>   This controls whether to automatically open a folder for automounted
>   media.
>
> If set to true, then Nautilus will automatically open a folder when
>   media is automounted. This only applies to media where no known
>   x-content/* type was detected; for media where a known x-content type
>   is detected, the user configurable action will be taken instead. This
>   can be configured as shown below.

Comment: urm... did this, but automounting is still happening

Comment: @Michael here just showed a message "connected" and another "is umounted" (in a sense that it wasnt even mounted I guess). So it stopped being auto mounted! ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I have an Android device and Windows running in a virtual machine. Disabling this enabled my device to connect to the virtual machine in MTP mode. Before, selecting MTP mode would cause the device to disconnect and then be remounted in the Ubuntu host before the Windows guest could take any action.